# MySQL Duplicate child data when Parent is duplicated

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, parent

I have 2 tables: `bases` (parent) and `base_formula` (child).

What I am after is the duplication of the child data, when the parent is copied (created).

Here is my mark up:

```
CREATE TABLE `bases` (
  `base_id_pk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `base_duplicate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `base_desc` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `base_material` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `base_material_percent` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `target_sg` decimal(4,3) NOT NULL,
  `base_material_unit` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `cost_per_kg` varchar(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `bulk_base_liquid_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `micro_sample` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `base_version` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `mod_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mod_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `change_reason` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `superseeds` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `department` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `base_formula` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `base_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `raw_material_id` varchar(1120) NOT NULL,
  `percent` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dispense` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `ignore_step` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main_ingredient` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cost_of_use` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active_flag` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`base_id` on `base_formula` is an FK linked to `base_id_pk` on bases.

I have `base_duplicate`, which is a field i was going to use to associate to the parent id i wanted to duplicate the child data from.

I am after building a trigger `BEFORE INSERT` if possible. My previous attempts caused mysql errors:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_base_duplication_formula` BEFORE INSERT ON `bases`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO base_formula(base_id,raw_material_id,percent,dispense,ignore_step,main_ingredient,cost_of_use,active_flag) 
    SELECT 
        NEW.base_id_pk, 
        bf.raw_material_id, 
        bf.percent, 
        bf.dispense, 
        bf.ignore_step,
        bf.main_ingredient, 
        bf.cost_of_use,
        0
    FROM base_formula bf 
    WHERE NEW.base_duplicate IS NOT NULL 
        AND new.base_duplicate=bf.base_id
```

Comment: First you should put your `INSERT` statement inside a `BEGIN ... END`, see [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) for the exact syntax you should use.